# Read rss and show as html

Tags: rss

I am using google reader for my RSS, i want to export all my shared or starred rss items to HTML to take this html and put on my website

Do any one have an idea about?
And one important thing as well, can i page through this html? i mean to export as pages not all in one html page to let the user on my site page through my starred feeds.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSTL you can transform XML to any format you want, including HTML. You can do the transformation on the server, or with modern browsers like IE6+ and Firefox2+ you can do the transformation on the client side. XSTL isn't very pretty as a programming language, but the concept is pretty neat.

I don't know if you can link directly to the RSS feed XML so that it's always up to date. I think Google requires that you authenticate and have permission to access the feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from an RSS with jQuery by selecting and iterating through the tags rather easily. Additionally, you can perform conditional-checks on attributes etc as well.